# How can I take advantage of Spring repositories if I am using RestFul Services?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, microservices, restful-architecture

I am currently working on a project using a microservice oriented architecture. I'm using Spring boot + MongoDB repositories so our team can save some time by not having to write the queries.

We are facing a problem with this approach. If we have the entity user:

```
{
"name":"Josh",
"lastname":"Smith"
"createdOn":"2018-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

And we want to expose this entity as a resource, but we don't really know what parameters the client will use to search on this repository, so we'll end up with something like:

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User>get(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String lastname){...}
```

And a repository:

`public List<User> findByName(String name);
public List<User> findByLastName(String lastname);
...`

We will have to create a lot of methods in the user repository and conditionals to use them to give an answer back according to the client's query. And this problem will grow as the entity gets more fields.

I know that spring supports [query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.introduction) but it won't work if we need to search by range of date for example.

Is there a way to take advantage of the Spring repositories even though we don't know what queries is our service receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this problem but one easy way is using a custom `QueryDTO` with the all the query properties like below.

```
public class QueryDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And in your Repository you can extend [QueryByExampleExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html)

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, QueryByExampleExecutor<User> {...}
```

And your controller method should do the following;

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> get(@RequestParam(value = "q") String query) {
    QueryDTO queryDto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(query, QueryDTO.class);

    // You can write a converter to convert QueryDTO to User Example  
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(queryDto.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(queryDto.getLastName());
    Example<User> example = Example.of(user);

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userRepository.findOne(example), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now it doesn't matter how many new fields you have you can just modify `QueryDTO` to add new fields and enable searching by those fields.

**UPDATE**

If you need to query by Ranges or with custom values you can extend [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslPredicateExecutor.html) in your `UserRepository`. But as the name suggests `QueryByExampleExecutor` only supports matching values.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the date range filters, if the user has a "creation date" and we want to search users created between X and Y?   From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.introduction) I understand it will only work for exact matching on that kind of fileds, right?

Comment: The answer is given based on your question. The best solution for your problem in the question is `QueryByExampleExecutor` but it has limitations of not supporting ranges (Date, Number etc.) if you want ranges then you need to look at QuerydslPredicateExecutor.

Comment: You're right. I'll complete my question and will check QuerydslPredicateExecutor too. Thanks,